# Misleading name for favorites tab sort option

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is not necessarily wrong or a bug but I think it could be a bit misleading.  I recently added a question as a favorite.  Later in the day I went to go look for it.  I immediately clicked "newest" thinking this meant the newly added favorite.  Come to find out I really should have clicked on "added".

I think the titles need some work to make it less ambiguous?

[image]

Newest could mean, most recently added, as it just happened to me.  I can imagine this happening to others?  It would have been less ambigious with something like "Added Most Recently"..if that takes too much UI room just make it a tooltip?  "Newest" should become "**Posted**".

**This tab is from the favorites tab of your profile page.**

Comment: Well it is confusing now that you make me think about it. Until now the 'added' option was just completely invisible to me because I don't understand it.

Comment: I'm glad you see my point..its not obvious until you haven't visited for quite some time and you try to do the sort.

Comment: I suggest changing "newest" to "posted". Then maybe grouping the two tabs together.

Comment: I don't see the *added* tab

Comment: I didn't know I was on new-nav @ryanyuyu

Comment: It's on [the favorites tab of your profile page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k6ki0.png) @ryanyuyu

Comment: @xPeke See above

Comment: @TinyGiant my mistake.  Deleting obsolete comments.

Comment: Can this be changed to a feature request or have that tag added?

Comment: While I can certainly _understand_ the confusion, I disagree that `newest` should be renamed as that term is consistent with every other page (that I'm aware of) that lists any link. For example, the questions page, or on a user's profile displaying their questions/answer/activity. I think renaming `newest` to `posted` on this page only would likely cause more confusion. The term `posted` in general is more ambiguous in my opinion. Perhaps `added` could become `newest favorites`? or something along those lines?

Comment: You just had to be @That1Guy ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I guess I did =P